# Как показать пользователь, что обязательный чекбокс не выбран

Tags: html, css, form

В форме есть чекбокс о политике конфиденциальности. Но у input[type="checkbox"] стоит display: none, для стилизации label. Как при отправке формы показать пользователю, что этот input обязателен? Добавление required к input ни к чему не приводит, так как он скрыт. Проблема решается через JS, но есть ли способ проще?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте для стилизации использовать appearance.

```css
form {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.mycheckbox {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border: 1px solid #777;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.mycheckbox::before {
  content: "\2714";
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

.mycheckbox:checked::before {
  visibility: visible;
}

.mycheckbox:checked {
  background: blue;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
 <input class='mycheckbox' type="checkbox" required> 
 <input type="submit" value='отправить'>
</form>
```